# Broken controller tests after installing Capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, capybara

I had a bunch of combined controller/view tests written with rspec. I added the Capybara gem and wrote some integrations tests which pass fine. The only problem is that now in all my controller tests, where I have

response.should have_selector("some selector")

rspec gives errors such as:

```
NoMethodError:
       undefined method `has_selector?' for #<ActionController::TestResponse:0xa03e7ec>
```

when I run controller tests. I'm guessing that Capybara is being used in my controller tests and has overwritten some Rspec methods. How can I fix this?

```
# gemfile.rb
group :test do
  gem 'rspec'
  gem "capybara"
  gem "launchy"
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '1.0'
end

# spec_helper.rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include IntegrationSpecHelper, :type => :request
end
```

Here's an example of a failing test:

```
# spec/controllers/books_controller_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'

describe BooksController do
  render_views

  it "should have the right page title" do
    get :show, :id => @book.ean
    response.should have_selector("title", :content => "Lexicase | " + @book.title)
  end
end
```

and it's associated error:

```
  1) BooksController GET 'show' should have the right page title
     Failure/Error: response.should have_selector("title", :content => "Lexicase | " + @book.title)
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `has_selector?' for #<ActionController::TestResponse:0xa8488c0>
     # ./spec/controllers/books_controller_spec.rb:23:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: Can you add you failing test ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were probably using Webrat earlier, and **has_selector?** is a Webrat matcher. Capybaras doesn't have a has_selector matcher, it has a matcher called **has_css**. You may want to replace the "has_selector" with "has_css".

Comment: You're right about Webrat anyway. As far as I can tell, there is a has_selector? method in Capybara (http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/RSpecMatchers) but it's on the page method rather than the request method. Another thing is that I don't think I can use "get :show" anymore like I could with webrat. I have to use visit(book_path(@book.ean)) instead. However visit can only issue get requests by design which makes it unsuitable for controller unit tests. There's a larger issue I'm missing here.

Comment: lol well it turns out that Capybara and Webrat are not mutually exclusive as I originally assumed. Problem solved imo!

Comment: I wish bloggers would stop calling Capybara a drop-in replacement for Webrat, or at least qualify the statement with the changes to your code that may be needed.  I've had to make lots of minor changes to get my code working after making the switch.

Comment: Yeh me too..its not a drop-in replacement

Answer (score 1):

Capybara helpers only works within requests specs. Either create a new request spec, or pass in :type => :request in the describe block part, like so:

```
describe "test for the testing test", :type => :request do
  it "should work with capybara" do
    visit root_path
    click_link "Home"
    page.should WHATEVA
  end
end
```

I realize this question was asked a long time ago, but I thought I would share anyway. GLHF