# RSpec Error while making RoR tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, specifications

I got an error while testing code from RoR tutorial, pls help with these issue, listing is below. May be wrong version of spec in Gemfile.

Failures:

```
  1) PagesController GET 'home' should have the right title
     Failure/Error: response.should have_selector("title", :content => "Home")
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `has_selector?' for #<ActionController::TestResponse:0x007fb3d4d2d108>
     # ./spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:14:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) PagesController GET 'contact' should have the right title
     Failure/Error: response.should have_selector("title", :content => "Contact")
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `has_selector?' for #<ActionController::TestResponse:0x007fb3d280b370>
     # ./spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:26:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  3) PagesController GET 'about' should have the right title
     Failure/Error: response.should have_selector("title", :content => "About")
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `has_selector?' for #<ActionController::TestResponse:0x007fb3d2b96e90>
     # ./spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:38:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  4) PagesController GET 'help' should have the right title
     Failure/Error: response.should have_selector("title", :content => "Help")
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `has_selector?' for #<ActionController::TestResponse:0x007fb3d28a19d8>
     # ./spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:50:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.1005 seconds
8 examples, 4 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:12 # PagesController GET 'home' should have the right title
rspec ./spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:24 # PagesController GET 'contact' should have the right title
rspec ./spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:36 # PagesController GET 'about' should have the right title
rspec ./spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:48 # PagesController GET 'help' should have the right title
```

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.3'

gem 'sqlite3'

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

group :test, :development do
  gem "rspec-rails", "~> 2.10.1"
end
```

pages_controller_spec.rb listing:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe PagesController do
  render_views

  describe "GET 'home'" do
    it "should be successful" do
      get 'home'
      response.should be_success
    end

    it "should have the right title" do
      get 'home'
      response.should have_selector("title", :content => "Home")
    end
  end

  describe "GET 'contact'" do
    it "should be successful" do
      get 'contact'
      response.should be_success
    end

    it "should have the right title" do
      get 'contact'
      response.should have_selector("title", :content => "Contact")
    end
  end

  describe "GET 'about'" do
    it "should be successful" do
      get 'about'
      response.should be_success
    end

    it "should have the right title" do
      get 'about'
      response.should have_selector("title", :content => "About")
    end
  end

  describe "GET 'help'" do
    it "should be successful" do
      get 'help'
      response.should be_success
    end

    it "should have the right title" do
      get 'help'
      response.should have_selector("title", :content => "Help")
    end
  end
end
```

I do not understang what is wrong.

Comment: That's a webrat method. Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5388638/broken-controller-tests-after-installing-capybara

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use webrat, you can use

```
response.body.should include 'Contact</h1>'
```

Rather than

```
response.should have_selector("title", :content => "Contact")
```

Which is a bit less clean, I agree.

Answer (score 0):

Re-edit your GEMFILE and type

```
gem 'webrat'
```

and then

type

```
bundle install
```